# "Held broken packages" when installing ia32-libs

Tags: linux, linux-mint, package-management

When I try to install the ia32-libs for ADB and fastboot using apt-get, I get a message stating I have held broken packages. When trying to use Aptitude instead, I am told that I need to downgrade some packages and furthermore uninstall four.

Is this a safe operation to perform?

I am running Linux Mint 16 "Petra" Cinnamon edition.

> ```
>             Remove the following packages:                                     
>        1)     gcj-4.8-jre                                                      
>        2)     gcj-4.8-jre-headless                                             
>        3)     gcj-jre                                                           
>        4)     gcj-jre-headless                                                 
>
>             Install the following packages:                                    
>        5)     lib32asan0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                             
>        6)     lib32atomic1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                           
>        7)     lib32gcc-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                       
>        8)     lib32gcc1 [1:4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                            
>        9)     lib32gomp1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                             
>       10)     lib32itm1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                              
>       11)     lib32quadmath0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                         
>       12)     lib32stdc++-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                    
>       13)     lib32stdc++6 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                           
>       14)     libc6-dev-i386 [2.17-93ubuntu4 (saucy)]                          
>       15)     libc6-dev-x32 [2.17-93ubuntu4 (saucy)]                           
>       16)     libc6-x32 [2.17-93ubuntu4 (saucy)]                               
>       17)     libkms1 [2.4.46-1 (saucy)]                                       
>       18)     libstdc++-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                      
>       19)     libx32asan0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                            
>       20)     libx32atomic1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                          
>       21)     libx32gcc-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                      
>       22)     libx32gcc1 [1:4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                           
>       23)     libx32gomp1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                            
>       24)     libx32itm1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                             
>       25)     libx32quadmath0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                        
>       26)     libx32stdc++-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]                   
>       27)     libx32stdc++6 [4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]
>
>             Downgrade the following packages:                                  
>       28)     cpp-4.8 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]       
>       29)     gcc-4.8 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]       
>       30)     gcc-4.8-base [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]  
>       31)     libasan0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]      
>       32)     libatomic1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]    
>       33)     libdrm-intel1 [2.4.46-1ubuntu1 (now) -> 2.4.46-1 (saucy)]        
>       34)     libdrm-nouveau2 [2.4.46-1ubuntu1 (now) -> 2.4.46-1 (saucy)]      
>       35)     libdrm-radeon1 [2.4.46-1ubuntu1 (now) -> 2.4.46-1 (saucy)]       
>       36)     libdrm2 [2.4.46-1ubuntu1 (now) -> 2.4.46-1 (saucy)]              
>       37)     libgcc-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]
>       38)     libgcc1 [1:4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 1:4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]   
>       39)     libgfortran3 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]  
>       40)     libgomp1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]      
>       41)     libitm1 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]       
>       42)     libquadmath0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]  
>       43)     libstdc++6 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]    
>       44)     libtsan0 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now) -> 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 (saucy)]      
>
>
>
> Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
> ```

Here is a full console log: http://pastebin.com/sj0fS8n2

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you're on a 64-bit Debian-derived system because you don't have the 32-bit libraries installed since the 32-bit architecture, by default, is not enabled on 64-bit systems. If you are running on a 64-bit Debian install, run the following to enable 32-bit packages:

```
dpkg --add-architecture <arch>
apt-get update
```

If you want to install a 32-bit package, run the command

```
apt-get install $package:$architecture
```

where `$package` is the package's name (e.g. `links`), and `$arch` is the architecture (e.g. `i386`).

[Documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)